# parfor index what is the initval for each work ID?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I met a problem when using parfor in matlab:

I know parfor will divide the work to several workers and each worker has its own index range as `parfor idx=initval: endval <body> end;`

The problem is for each worker, I need to do something when `idx==initval`, which is different from other index value (such as print something so that I know roughly what it's doing now, but I don't need to do it for every index value).

In the `for...end` procedure, I clearly know where the index begins, but I don't know how to do it in parfor.

Do you have any suggestions? thanks in advance.

```
for i=1:n
  if(i==1)
    fprintf('I am at the beginning of this loop\n!');
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you give an example using a for loop? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thank you Daniel, I added a simple example of for loop, this is only for explain the situation. The example seems useless, but actually I can do something else if I can distinguish the index is at the beginning or later.

Comment: you do not have control over how the work gets allocated with `parfor`. look into `spmd` blocks.